# Error when saving model with tensorflow-agents

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-agents, tf-agent

I am trying to save a model with tensorflow-agents. First I define the following:

```
collect_policy = tf_agent.collect_policy
saver = PolicySaver(collect_policy, batch_size=None)
```

and then save the model like this:

```
saver.save('my_directory/')
```

This works ok in google colab but I am getting the following error in my local PC.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.nested_structure_coder' has no attribute 'StructureCoder'
```

These are the library versions I am using:

tensorflow                   2.9.1

tf-agents                    0.11.0

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am using `tensorflow 2.9.0` and `tf-agents 0.13.0` with `tf-probabilities 0.17.0` and running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr**

Make sure you have the right tensorflow-probability version that is compatible for 2.9.x and tf-agents 0.11.0

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-probability
pip install tensorflow-probability==0.17.0
```

(`0.19.0` for TF `2.11`, `0.18.0` for TF `2.10` or look at the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/releases))

Also make sure to restart your kernel from the notebook.

**What the problem was**

StructureCoder has been moved to tensorflow API. Therefore, other dependent libraries have made changes like [this in tf-agent](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/commit/137aa250333ee2e3b87df380c16daf49f66baffe) and like [this in tensorflow-probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blame/e3d67c00ab491f4314a3d3e8c2cde19c8aa7490e/tensorflow_probability/python/experimental/util/composite_tensor.py#L24). Your machine is somehow picking up an older version that depends on the previous version of `nested_structure_coder`.

For me, I was using
`tensorflow 2.9.0`
`tf-agents 0.13.0`
`tensorflow-probabilities 0.17.0`

Try making an explicit import in your notebook:

```
import tensorflow_probability
print(tensorflow_probability.__version__) # was 0.17.0 for me
```